# Django Annotate issue

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

I wish to do an SQL-like "Group by, Count" on django. Here are my current progress of the code:

```
tags = tag.objects.values('tag').annotate(Count('tag')).order_by()
```

Class for tag:

```
class tag(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField('id',primary_key=True,null=False)
    question_id = models.ForeignKey(question,null=False)
    tag = models.TextField('tag',null=True)
```

So, my question is whether the above query can get the possible SQL-like "Group by, Count"? If yes, how should I get the count value?

Comment: You are using `Count` on `text field` Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the annotated value:

```
tags = tag.objects.values('tag').annotate(tag_count=Count('tag')).order_by()
for tag in tags:
    print tag['tag_count']
```

Also you can use the annotated value in your `order_by`:

```
tags = tag.objects.values('tag').annotate(tag_count=Count('tag')).order_by('-tag_count')
```

Comment: hmm, why does my "tag.tag_count" gives an error? --> 'dict' object has no attribute 'tag_count'

Comment: Oh sorry it is retuning a dictionary instead of objects, because of `group by` try `tag['tag_count']`